# Fotorama thumnail block in fixed size

Tags: fotorama

How can i set thumbnails container width? I have 8 pictures and more in the slider. But in the thumbnail panel i need to show only 3.

```
<div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs">
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/3.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/4.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/3.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vampiire/8maq1zwL/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following:

"navwidth"
Navigation container width in pixels or percents.

Found at: http://fotorama.io/customize/options/